# I cannot resolve the equalsIgnoreCase in android Studio

Tags: java, android

I am a new in developing android application by using android studio.
I am trying to develop a quiz application by the help of some tutorials but I am stuck on a point that I cannot resolve equalsIgnoreCase.
Below is coding that I used in my JAVA class. Please help me and point out where I did wrong.

```
public class QuizActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

TextView tv;
Button btnNext;
RadioGroup rg;
RadioButton rb1,rb2,rb3,rb4;
String questions[]={"Pakistan found in?","Pakistan defence day?","First Governer General of Pakistan?"};
String answers[]={"1947","6 sep","Quid-i-Azam Muhammad Ali Jinnah"};
String choices[]={"1947","1946","1948","1945","7 sep","6 sep","8 sep","5 sep","Allama Muhammad Iqbal","Khan Liaqat Ali Khan","Quid-i-Azam Muhmmad Ali Jinnah","Tipu Sultan"};

int flag=0;
public static int marks,correct,wrong;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);

    tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvque);
    btnNext=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnnext);
    rg=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
    rb1=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio1);
    rb2=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio2);
    rb3=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio3);
    rb4=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio4);

    tv.setText(questions[flag]);
    rb1.setText(choices[0]);
    rb2.setText(choices[1]);
    rb3.setText(choices[2]);
    rb4.setText(choices[3]);

    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    RadioButton uanswers=(RadioButton)findViewById(rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
    String answerText=uanswers.getText().toString();
    if(uanswers.equalsIgnoreCase(answers[flag]));
    {
        correct++;
    }
    else
    {
        wrong++;
    }
    flag++;
    if(flag<questions.length) {
        tv.setText(questions[flag]);
        rb1.setText(choices[flag * 4]);
        rb2.setText(choices[flag * 4] + 1);
        rb3.setText(choices[flag * 4] + 2);
        rb4.setText(choices[flag * 4] + 3);
    }
    Intent in=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ResultActivity.class);
    StartActivity(in);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your code, it's look like typo mistake, `equalsIgnoreCase` is not available for `RadioButton`, but available for `String` class.

So here, your code is like

```
RadioButton uanswers=(RadioButton)findViewById(rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
String answerText=uanswers.getText().toString();
if(uanswers.equalsIgnoreCase(answers[flag])){
    correct++;
}
```

But i think it should be like, To compare answer with selected answer:

```
RadioButton uanswers=(RadioButton)findViewById(rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
String answerText=uanswers.getText().toString();
if(answerText.equalsIgnoreCase(answers[flag])){  // Use answerText instead of uanswers
    correct++;
}
```

Comment: but equalsIgnoreCase is still red in android studio and it is never suggesting me anything in suggestion option. I think I made some stupidity with settings or something like this.

Comment: Have you removed "**;**" from the end of if statement?

Comment: I don't think so. Please look at coding that I provided and point it out if statement and suggest what should I need to do.

Comment: Why did you put ";" at end of this statement? **if(uanswers.equalsIgnoreCase(answers[flag]));**